# speed up ideas -- can CUDA help here?

Tags: cuda

I'm working on an algorithm that has to do a small number 
of operations on a large numbers of small arrays, somewhat independently.

To give an idea:

- 1k sorting of arrays of length typically of 0.5k-1k elements.
- 1k of LU-solve of matrices that have rank 10-20.

everything is in floats.

Then, there is some horizontality to this problem: the above 
operations have to be carried independently on 10k arrays.

Also, the intermediate results need not be stored: for example, i don't 
need to keep the sorted arrays, only the sum of the smallest $m$ elements.

The whole thing has been programmed in c++ and runs. My question is: 
 would you expect a problem like this to enjoy significant speed ups 
 (factor 2 or more) with CUDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this in 5 lines of [ArrayFire](http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire) code.  I'm getting speedups of ~6X with this over the CPU.  I'm getting speedups of ~4X with this over Thrust (which was designed for vectors, not matrices).  Since you're only using a single GPU, you can run ArrayFire Free version.

```
array x = randu(512,1000,f32);
array y = sort(x); // sort each 512-element column independently
array x = randu(15,15,1000,f32), y;
gfor (array i, x.dim(2))
  y(span,span,i) = lu(x(span,span,i)); // LU-decomposition of each 15x15 matrix
```

Keep in mind that GPUs perform best when memory accesses are aligned to multiples of 32, so a bunch of 32x32 matrices will perform better than a bunch of 31x31.

Comment: Thanks also for the pointer to ArrayFire (which lead me to intel's ipp functions which seems interesting in there own right). I can't choose the matrices size :(. Can you detail what seep ups you get on the sort part and the LU part separatly? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, didn't save the breakdown numbers. Whipped this up in a hurry. Good thing is that this is giving good results despite x not aligning with 32x32 matrices (i.e. uses 15x15). Perhaps you can run and see what you get on your machine.

Comment: it's not even clear to me in which language *this is writen:) Python?

Comment: That is C++, but there is a Python version too if you want that instead.

Comment: no, c++ is better :)....for now i'm trying the ideas suggested by Paul R but 'll get back to ArrayFire. Thanks for the putting a number on the differences between GPU and CPU for this application.

Answer (score 1):

If you "only" need a factor of 2 speed up I would suggest looking at more straightforward optimisation possibilities first, before considering GPGPU/CUDA. E.g. assuming x86 take a look at using SSE for a potential 4x speed up by re-writing performance critical parts of your code to use 4 way floating point SIMD. Although this would tie you to x86 it would be more portable in that it would not require the presence of an nVidia GPU.

Having said that, there may even be simpler optimisation opportunities in your code base, such as eliminating redundant operations (useless copies and initialisations are a favourite) or making your memory access pattern more cache-friendly. Try profiling your code with a decent profiler to see where the bottlenecks are.

Note however that in general sorting is not a particularly good fit for either SIMD or CUDA, but other operations such as LU decomposition may well benefit.

Comment: the vast majority of the time spent are in the children's of stl's sort and eigen's LU decomposition. Because the task is so repetitive, there is very little initialization/copy going on. The code is already compiled with the SSE and AVX flags on. Portability is a secondary concern at this point. Thanks for the pointer to 4 way SIMD --though i believe this is already handled by eigen.

Comment: Note that compiling with SSE/AVX flags does not necessarily generate any SIMD code (some compilers such as ICC and newer versions of gcc with appropriate switches can do some basic auto-vectorization, but it's pretty limited). Note also that AVX does 8 way float SIMD, so if you can assume an AVX-capable CPU then there may be some 8 way SIMD optimisation opportunities which are not currently exploited by the libraries that you are using.

Comment: "SSE/AVX flags does not necessarily generate any SIMD code" Would you have a good introduction on how to DIY this? ---i.e how to write code that benefit from SIMD (potentially AVX)?

Comment: It's a big subject, but there are quite a few useful examples here on SO where people have asked how to implement existing scalar code using SIMD. Try searching for the `[sse]`, `[avx]` or `[simd]` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few pointers, you maybe already incorporated:

1) If you just need the m smallest elements, you are probably better of to just search the smallest element, remove it and repeat m - times.

2) Did you already parallelize the code on the cpu? OpenMP or so ...

3) Did you think about buying better hardware? (I know it´s not the nice think to do, but if you want to reach performance goals for a specific application it´s sometimes the cheapest possibility ...)

If you want to do it on CUDA, it should work conceptually, so no big problems should occur. However, there are always the little things, which depend on experience and so on.

Consider the thrust-library for the sorting thing, hopefully someone else can suggest some good LU-decomposition algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your comments: 1) in my case log(n)<m 2) yes, no problem there 3) i want to improve relative performance, actually :). My question is more along the lines of "could CUDA help in this setting" (looking on the web i'm not sure, it seems CUDA would only help for big sorting/LU tasks).  Thanks for the pointer to thrust.

Comment: If you have big sorting tasks, you have to break them down in many smaller tasks to take full advantage of CUDA. So if you have already small tasks, you don´t have to think about this. The only thing one has to think about is the proportion of computation time to memory transfer time.